# exponential race jump chain process: probability matrix

Tags: stochastic-processes

Let $(X_t)_{t\in\Bbb R_{\ge0}}$ be a random process on a countable state space $I$.

For each state $i_{n-1}\in I$ let $E_1,E_2,...$ be independent random variables s.t. $E_j \sim Exp(\lambda_{i_{n-1},j})$ models the time to pass from state $i_{n-1}$ to $j$.

At each step the shortest $E_{i_{n-1},j}$ "wins the race" and the process goes from state $i_{n-1}$ to the state $j$ that corresponds to the winner.

My question is: why do we have $\Bbb P(X(T_n)=j\mid X(T_{n-1})=i)=\frac{\lambda_{i,j}}{\sum\limits_{k\ne i}\lambda_{k,j}}$, where $T_n$ are the jumping times?

Answer (score 0):

Please note, that there must be some conditions on $\lambda_{ij}$, which were not stated. For example, $\sum_{j} \lambda_{ij} < \infty$ for each $i$.

According to me, the properties of the exponential distribution suggests the answer to our question. Assume that you are in the state $i_{n-1}$. In this state you wait time = minimum time until the next transition. Since all transitions are exponentially dsitributed, minimum has also exponential distribution with the parameter $\Lambda_{i_{n-1}}=\sum_{j, j\neq i_{n-1}} \lambda_{i_{n-1},j}$. Then the probability that this minimal time is equal to the the time to jump to $i_n$ is equal to $\lambda_{i_{n-1},i_n}/\Lambda_{i_{n-1}}$. There are several ways to show this. You can find strict proofs in many books. For example, see Lemma 1.2.3 in [this book](https://books.google.ru/books?id=2BREaX4EunkC&printsec=frontcover&hl=ru#v=onepage&q&f=false) (P. P. Bocharov, C. D'Apice, A. V. Pechinkin. Queueing Theory. Modern Probability and Statistics. Walter de Gruyter, 2011.)